# Show yearly profile over each other in same sheet: Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, timeserieschart

[image]

In the image attached below, How can I show years over one another instead of being them side by side for each month in a year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move Year(Date) from the Color shelf to the Rows shelf to get a row for each year.